# Stall on main thread error XCUITest

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

I have my test suite for my iOS app, however some of tests are quite flaky and not always passing. I have rooted this down to a `stall on the main thread` error.

This happens in my extension class

```
extension XCTestCase {

func tapElement(element: XCUIElement)
{
    waitForElementToAppear(element: element)
    XCTAssert(element.exists)
    element.tap()
}

func waitForElementToAppear(element: XCUIElement,
                              file: String = #file,
                              line: UInt = #line)
{
     let existsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
    expectation(for: existsPredicate,
                            evaluatedWith: element, handler: nil)

    waitForExpectations(timeout: 5) { (error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            let message = "Failed to find \(element) after 5 seconds."
            self.recordFailure(withDescription: message,
                                              inFile: file,
                                              atLine: line,
                                              expected: true)
        }
    }
  }

}
```

Where it throws the error
`canOpenURL: failed for URL: "gplus://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme gplus"
2017-05-26 11:36:50.999 myapp[73681:1851577] Falling back to loading access token from NSUserDefaults because of simulator bug`

Has anyone experienced this problem before? If so how did you deal with the problem ... thanks in advance

Comment: It's unlikely that log is related to your error, as it says it is using a fallback. The stall on the main thread is probably from elsewhere in your app.